# How do I know a chest is nearby?

Tags: destiny

In Destiny, there are chests all over the place. Is there anything that tells me when one is nearby or do I have to just keep my eyes open?

Comment: I won't post this as an answer yet as I can't confirm it, but the [Mida Multi-tool](http://www.reddit.com/r/DestinyTheGame/comments/2gq5zc/got_my_first_exotic_tonight_in_the_raid_its/) might help.  I have one and will test it out in the near future.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you get close to one there is a kinda jangly sound. You can also often see the glow of them from inside a cave without going in (for some of the cave types).

They do tend to spawn in fairly predictable places, so as you play you'll get a feeling for where to look for them. One thing to note is that they spawn based on people being in the area and if there's a lot of traffic through an area without many people hitting less obvious spawn locations you can often find quite a few at once. Venus where the Fallen are fighting the Vex and the "prevent the sacrifices" world event happens is a great place for this.

Comment: There is also [MIDA Multi-Tool](http://destiny.wikia.com/wiki/MIDA_Multi-Tool) It has a metal detector type effect that helps find chests and materials.

Answer (score -3):

Nothing shows up on your motion tracker and there is no audible cues when a chest is nearby. You just have to keep your eyes open for those green lights that are on the chest.

Comment: There is an audible cue, although it can be difficult to hear.